# Load testing tools for IIS6+

Tags: testing, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5, load-testing

I'm hosting an mvc4 web api and would like to know what are some good load/perf testing tools?

I just want to send an http get and make sure it isn't being cached by the server (my app) each time.

(i.e) -> http://mysrv.com/api/dev/loadtest?data=1

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into wcat:

http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2007/05/wcat-63-(x86)
http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2007/05/wcat-63-(x64)

It does exactly the kind of load testing you want.